# Turning off the scroll-to-zoom functionality in CartoDB

Tags: carto, zoom

I have the following [post](http://www.the10and3.com/how-people-in-calgary-get-to-work/) that has four embedded full width maps. When you scroll down the post and the cursor is over one of the maps, it stops the scroll to zoom in on the map. Is it possible to turn off that functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Click on `Options` on the CARTO Editor's left bottom corner, and disable the `Scroll wheel zoom` option.

Comment: Oddly enough, it is already disabled. When I'm in the editor, the scroll wheel zoom function doesn't work. It only seems to "turn itself back on" after the map is embedded within a post.

Comment: I have reported the issue to the CARTO's Product team [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/9585).